# finding a value belongs to array or not in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have following JavaScript Array

```
business: [{
      "id": 22,
      "name": "Private",
      "max_mem": 0,
      "gen_roomtype_id": 4,
      "status": 1,
      "type": 0,
      "set_value": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Standard ward",
      "max_mem": 0,
      "gen_roomtype_id": 2,
      "status": 1,
      "type": 0,
      "set_value": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 7,
      "name": "Semi Private",
      "max_mem": 0,
      "gen_roomtype_id": 3,
      "status": 1,
      "type": 0,
      "set_value": 1
    }],      

"gen": [{
      "id": 5,
      "name": "laboratory",
      "description": "",
      "sharing": 0,
      "set_value": 2
    }],
```

And i have a idArray as following

```
idArray: [5, 7]
```

i would like to know whether the idArray values are belongs to "gen" Array or 
"business" Array.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: what do u mean? unless they are both inside an array themselves you can't not know, beacause you need to loop that specific array to get the results

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - right now you have a snippet of some not understandable object

Comment: @Mr.Developer ,i have tried with for loop, i am not using JavaScript predefined functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `every`

*This approach assumes the input data is an object.*

```js
var obj = {  business: [{      "id": 5,      "name": "Private",      "max_mem": 0,      "gen_roomtype_id": 4,      "status": 1,      "type": 0,      "set_value": 1    },    {      "id": 6,      "name": "Standard ward",      "max_mem": 0,      "gen_roomtype_id": 2,      "status": 1,      "type": 0,      "set_value": 1    },    {      "id": 7,      "name": "Semi Private",      "max_mem": 0,      "gen_roomtype_id": 3,      "status": 1,      "type": 0,      "set_value": 1    }  ],  "gen": [{    "id": 5,    "name": "laboratory",    "description": "",    "sharing": 0,    "set_value": 2  }]
};

var idArray = [5, 7];

var resultBusiness = idArray.every(n => obj.business.some(b => b.id === n));
var resultGen = idArray.every(n => obj.gen.some(b => b.id === n));

console.log("All in business: ", resultBusiness);
console.log("All in Gen: ", resultGen);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```